# send data to class using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax

Can you please assist me: I am creating a Student System I want to use the methods not servlet doPost or doGet,my method id saveStudent but it does not sent the data through,I am using j

```js
$.ajax({
    url: com/StudentSystem/student/saveStudent, //have included the method
    type: "post",
    data: {"emailAddress": emailAddress},
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
            
    }
});
```

```html
<form  name="student" method="post" action="index.jsp">
    <table > 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="save" id="btnSave" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

query/ajax

Comment: `'com/StudentSystem/student/saveStudent'`? - missing string literal notation

Comment: instead of package path use the controller's method and yes in string literal notation.

Comment: @Arun P thank you for your immediate response.it solved the problem.

Comment: @Jai your suggestions helped alot because now Im getting another error message..I really appreciate your assistance.